# WPF Application stealing focus

Tags: c#, wpf

What i want to do:

I want my WPF app to successfully type in keystrokes onto any other application that has text fields, for example, notepad.

What the problem is:

If i press any button that simulates a keystroke ('A', for example), my app steals focus and now that 'notepad' is not focused/active anymore, my button does not know where to send the keystroke,

What im requesting:  How do i get my WPF app to not steal the focus of any other app so that i can successfully type in a keystroke when i press my app's buttons, here's my code:

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("1");

    }
```

'InputSimulator' comes from a library that i got online, it makes simulating keystrokes easy.

**Update, for clarification, i want something like Surface Pro Keyboard, this keyboard does exactly what i want to do, if i press on it's keyboard, the app that is currently active stays focused and sp3 keyboard is able to enter a keystroke, how do i do this for MY app?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to p/invoke `user32.dll`, use `FindWindow` to get a handle for the application you are trying to write to, then use `SetForegroundWindow`. Then you can send keystrokes to that window.

See the article on MSDN for a quick sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

You can also find tons of examples by searching google for p/invoke and Windows API.

Comment: i tried this stuff and it semi-works, what i want is my app to not get focus/activation when i press it's buttons, if my app does not steal focus, the app that IS focused (notepad) can get the keystrokes